# Why I get this error after run 'yarn start'?

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have already run my projects without error with yarn. But now, it gives the below error(I tried for multiple projects):

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: have you installed anything using --force or with any conflicts.

Comment: @JEFFRINJACOB No, I didn't. I have already run this without error with yarn. I don't know why it is not run now.